# html5 form validation is not working when input type is submit is used

Tags: html, webforms

HI i want to validate an input type=email field with a submit button.
I have two form element in the page. And i am opening a div(divForgotPassword) as a modal.
But the required attribute is not working inside the modal .
Below is my my code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

//some elements

```
 <form id="form2" action="javascript:RetrievePassword();">
      <div id="divForgotPassword" style="display:none" title="Forgot password">

                  <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblForgotPassword" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="email" required="required" id="txtForgotEmail" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" style="background-image:url('Images/buttons/btn_send.png')" id="btnSend"  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Which browsers are you using to test this? Not all HTML5 elements and attributes are supported across all popular browsers: [Browser Support for New HTML5 Input Attributes](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/#attributes)

Comment: Sandeep, You haven't written any html tag for input type = "email" in your code.

Comment: I am using chrome browser.I suppose it supports html5..?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form2" action="javascript:RetrievePassword();">
<div id="divForgotPassword"  title="Forgot password">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="txtForgotEmail">
                    EMAIL : </label>
            <td>

                <input type="email" required="required" id="txtForgotEmail" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" style="background-image:url('Images/buttons/btn_send.png')" id="btnSend" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

please find this demo [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h6usc/)